# fill combobox with data in a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am trying to populate my combobox with names in my stored procedure.

```
public frmAddEdit(Book book, Author author)
    {
        _book = book;
        _author = author;
        _dataAccess = DataAccess.GetInstance;
        _dataAccess.SetConnectionString(_dataAccess.GetServerConnectionString());
        ComboFill();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

this is my load form

```
public void AddEditBook_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtTitle.Text = _book.Title;
        //comboBox1.DataSource = _book.FullName;
        //comboBox1.ValueMember = "AuthorId";
        //comboBox1.DisplayMember = "FullName";
        ComboFill();
        //txtAuthor.Text = _author.FullName;
       //txtAdd.Text = book.Title;
    }
```

my combobox

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView view = comboBox1.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
        string fullName = view["FullName"].ToString();


    }
```

something i saw online and tried it.

```
         public void ComboFill()
    {
        DataRow dr;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dr = dt.NewRow();
       // dr.ItemArray = new object[] { 0, "Select Author" };
        dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
        comboBox1.DataSource = _book.FullName;
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "AuthorId";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "FullName";
    }
```

Comment: why you do complex when you can do it in an easy way?

Comment: Type `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox` as no property named `ValueMember` or `DisplayMember`.

Comment: So,what is your question? You've got any error? what's the problem?

Comment: This code could be modified tremendously for improvement, but the simplest way to get this (probably) functioning is to move the `ComboFill()` method after `InitializeComponent()` call in your constructor. The `InitializeComponent` method is where the ComboBox is instantiated.  I'm surprised your application even runs.  When you first execute `ComboFill`, the ComboBox doesn't even exist yet.

Comment: @Pikoh i am trying to bring the saved fullnames in my sql to populate in my combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//assume this that you have datatable filled from stored procedure
//This is sample for populating your combo
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("AuthorID", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("FullName", typeof(string));

DataRow dr = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   dr = dt.NewRow();
   dr[0] = i;
   dr[1] = "ABC" + i + 2 * i;

   dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

comboBox1.DataSource = dt; // this will be populated from SP
comboBox1.ValueMember = "AuthorID";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "FullName";
```

Comment: DataRow dr = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   dr = dt.NewRow();
   dr[0] = i;
   dr[1] = "ABC" + i + 2 * i;

   dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

Comment: i want it to bring the four authors names in the data into the combobox

Answer (score 1):

the `comboBox1.DataSource = _bool.FullName;` is wrong. It should be:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = _book;
```

Comment: I wonder whats is the point in in filling a conbobox with just one item, if there could be more than one element, you should check J.SMTBCJ15's answer http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42625890/edit

Comment: Yes there is data now in mu combobox, but i want the fullnames that is saved in my database to show in the combobox

Comment: At SO, people can help only not the whole code @SMG . You have good-luck that this question is not down-voted. If you are still unable to understand from above answer than have a look at this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/009464/bind-combobox-in-window-application-using-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I fixed it using SqlDataAdapter and passing it my stored procedure

```
public void PopulateDropdown()    
{   
    // Check to see if connection is closed, to be safe, if closed then open
    if (connection_db.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        connection_db.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter sqlData = new SqlDataAdapter("StoredProcedureHere", connection_db);

    // Must specify 'SelectCommand' when using get queries
    sqlData.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    // Store data in table
    sqlData.Fill(table);


    dropdownForNames.ValueMember = "player_id";
    dropdownForNames.DisplayMember = "name";
    dropdownForNames.DataSource = table;


    // Close connection
    connection_db.Close();
}
```